# Blackberry Porting From Android Error

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, blackberry-10, blackberry-android

I am porting an application from Android to BB10.

While deploying the application, i get this:

```
Info: Action: Install
Info: File size: 1060781
Info: Installing ...
Info: Processing 1060781 bytes
Info: Progress 50%...
Info: Progress 100%...
actual_dname::com.example.senior3.gYABgIO9J715uJCnmmg4HYrk23o
actual_id::gYABgIO9J715uJCnmmg4HYrk23o
actual_version::1.0.1.0
result::failure -12
com.qnx.bbt.deploy.Deploy$DeployException: result::failure -12
```

What does -12 mean? I'm guessing this is the error code.

After that, the application on my Blackberry Q10 can be seen, but doesn't load(crashes automatically) when opened.

I have tried to google the error without any luck. I have also tried looking it up on blackberry developers and, also, no luck there.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Error Code -12 stands for if you're using an Android SDK version higher than what is supported on the device.

You'll need to build using a supported version of Android SDK.  Assuming you are using BlackBerry OS 10.2.1, you need to build targeting Android Jelly Bean 4.2.2 or lower.

Check the OS version of device in which you are deploying your app.

PS: http://crackberry.com/talking-os-1021-and-android-apps-bb10-w-blackberrys-vp-developer-relations-and-ecosystem-builder